# Connecting labels and points with arrows

Tags: qgis, labeling

I found a previous thread on this and I am following this option.  I am hoping someone can split this into greater steps for me.  I am not certain of the detailed steps for creating a Generator Expression.

Can you expand on this process?

[image]

Comment: Please give more info about the steps you have made in the thread and what is your goal

Comment: If the @thread” was a Q&A on this site, or in any event, please provide a link to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achive something like this

[image]

do the following:

1. Open your `attribute table` and create two new fields. Name them `label_x` and `label_y`. Make sure to set their field type to `double` and `length to 10` and `precision to 8`. (This should cover most crs. Of course you can choose different values.)

[image]

2. Open your `label tab` of your layer and navigate to `placement` `data defined`. Choose your two fields you just created as source.

[image]

3. Open your `symbology tab` of your layer. Click the `small green plus button` and choose `geometry generator`.

[image]

Change geometry type to `linestring` and enter the following code

```
make_line(make_point($x,$y),make_point("label_x","label_y"))
```

[image]

Now select `simple line` from the drop down menu above and change it to `arrow`.

[image]

Choose the settings you wish to have for your arrow.

[image]

**Addition: How to do this for categorized points**

a) choose categorized and change your symbol

[image]

b) now set up your symbol as mentioned above in step 3.

[image]

c) finally hit the classify button

[image]